# what is the problem with my rust diesel pagination code

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I want to do a pagination query when using rust diesel `diesel = { version = "1.4.7", features = ["postgres","32-column-tables"] }` , this is my pagination code:

```
use diesel::prelude::*;
use diesel::query_dsl::methods::LoadQuery;
use diesel::query_builder::{QueryFragment, Query, AstPass};
use diesel::pg::Pg;
use diesel::sql_types::BigInt;
use diesel::QueryId;

pub trait PaginateForQueryFragment: Sized {
    fn paginate(self, page: i64) -> Paginated<Self>;
}

impl<T> PaginateForQueryFragment for T
    where T: QueryFragment<Pg>{
    fn paginate(self, page: i64) -> Paginated<Self> {
        Paginated {
            query: self,
            per_page: 10,
            page,
            is_sub_query: true,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, QueryId)]
pub struct Paginated<T> {
    query: T,
    page: i64,
    per_page: i64,
    is_sub_query: bool
}

impl<T> Paginated<T> {
    pub fn per_page(self, per_page: i64) -> Self {
        Paginated { per_page, ..self }
    }

    
    pub fn load_and_count_pages<U>(self, conn: &PgConnection) -> QueryResult<(Vec<U>, i64)>
        where
            Self: LoadQuery<PgConnection, (U, i64)>,
    {
        let per_page = self.per_page;
        let results = self.load::<(U, i64)>(conn)?;
        let total = results.get(0).map(|x| x.1).unwrap_or(0);
        let records = results.into_iter().map(|x| x.0).collect();
        let total_pages = (total as f64 / per_page as f64).ceil() as i64;
        Ok((records, total_pages))
    }
}

impl<T: Query> Query for Paginated<T> {
    type SqlType = (T::SqlType, BigInt);
}

impl<T> RunQueryDsl<PgConnection> for Paginated<T> {}


impl<T> QueryFragment<Pg> for Paginated<T>
    where
        T: QueryFragment<Pg>,
{
    fn walk_ast(&self, mut out: AstPass<Pg>) -> QueryResult<()> {
        out.push_sql("SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER () FROM ");
        if self.is_sub_query {
            out.push_sql("(");
        }
        self.query.walk_ast(out.reborrow())?;
        if self.is_sub_query {
            out.push_sql(")");
        }
        out.push_sql(" t LIMIT ");
        out.push_bind_param::<BigInt, _>(&self.per_page)?;
        out.push_sql(" OFFSET ");
        let offset = (self.page - 1) * self.per_page;
        out.push_bind_param::<BigInt, _>(&offset)?;
        Ok(())
    }
}


#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, QueryId)]
pub struct QuerySourceToQueryFragment<T> {
    query_source: T,
}

impl<FC, T> QueryFragment<Pg> for QuerySourceToQueryFragment<T>
    where
        FC: QueryFragment<Pg>,
        T: QuerySource<FromClause=FC>,
{
    fn walk_ast(&self, mut out: AstPass<Pg>) -> QueryResult<()> {
        self.query_source.from_clause().walk_ast(out.reborrow())?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

pub trait PaginateForQuerySource: Sized {
    fn paginate(self, page: i64) -> Paginated<QuerySourceToQueryFragment<Self>>;
}

impl<T> PaginateForQuerySource for T
    where T: QuerySource {
    fn paginate(self, page: i64) -> Paginated<QuerySourceToQueryFragment<Self>> {
        Paginated {
            query: QuerySourceToQueryFragment {query_source: self},
            per_page: 10,
            page,
            is_sub_query: false, 
        }
    }
}
```

then I do the pagination query in a unit test like this way:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod test {

    use std::env;
    use diesel::{Connection, ExpressionMethods, PgConnection, QueryDsl, RunQueryDsl};
    use rust_wheel::common::query::pagination::PaginateForQuerySource;
    use crate::model::diesel::rhythm::rhythm_schema::favorites::dsl::favorites;
    use crate::model::diesel::rhythm::rhythm_schema::favorites::like_status;
    use crate::models::Favorites;

    #[test]
    fn page_test(){
        use crate::model::diesel::rhythm::rhythm_schema::favorites::dsl::*;
        use rust_wheel::common::query::pagination::{PaginateForQueryFragment, PaginateForQuerySource};
        let conn = establish_music_connection();
        let query = favorites
            .filter(like_status.eq(1))
            .paginate(1)
            .per_page(10)
            .load::<Favorites>(&conn)
            .expect("query fav failed");

        println!("{:?}", 1);
    }

    pub fn establish_music_connection() -> PgConnection {
        let database_url = std::env::var("MUSIC_DATABASE_URL").expect("MUSIC_DATABASE_URL must be set");
        PgConnection::establish(&database_url).expect(&format!("Error connecting to {}", database_url))
    }
}
```

shows error like this:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `(i64, std::option::Option<i64>, i64, i64, i64, std::string::String, i32, i32, i64, i32, std::option::Option<i32>, std::option::Option<i32>): Queryable<((BigInt, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<BigInt>, BigInt, BigInt, BigInt, Text, Integer, Integer, BigInt, Integer, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>), BigInt), Pg>` is not satisfied
    --> src/test/app/music/fav/fav_music.rs:21:14
     |
21   |             .load::<Favorites>(&conn)
     |              ^^^^ the trait `Queryable<((BigInt, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<BigInt>, BigInt, BigInt, BigInt, Text, Integer, Integer, BigInt, Integer, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>), BigInt), Pg>` is not implemented for `(i64, std::option::Option<i64>, i64, i64, i64, std::string::String, i32, i32, i64, i32, std::option::Option<i32>, std::option::Option<i32>)`
     |
     = help: the following implementations were found:
               <(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L) as Queryable<(SA, SB, SC, SD, SE, SF, SG, SH, SI, SJ, SK, SL), __DB>>
               <(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L) as Queryable<diesel::sql_types::Record<(SA, SB, SC, SD, SE, SF, SG, SH, SI, SJ, SK, SL)>, Pg>>
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Queryable<((BigInt, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<BigInt>, BigInt, BigInt, BigInt, Text, Integer, Integer, BigInt, Integer, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<Integer>), BigInt), Pg>` for `Favorites`
    --> src/models.rs:14:22
     |
14   | #[derive( Serialize, Queryable, Deserialize,Default)]
     |                      ^^^^^^^^^
15   | // #[table_name = "favorites"]
16   | pub struct Favorites {
     |            ^^^^^^^^^
     = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<PgConnection, Favorites>` for `Paginated<diesel::query_builder::SelectStatement<rhythm_schema::favorites::table, query_builder::select_clause::DefaultSelectClause, query_builder::distinct_clause::NoDistinctClause, query_builder::where_clause::WhereClause<diesel::expression::operators::Eq<rhythm_schema::favorites::columns::like_status, diesel::expression::bound::Bound<Integer, i32>>>>>`
note: required by a bound in `load`
    --> /Users/dolphin/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/diesel-1.4.8/src/query_dsl/mod.rs:1238:15
     |
1238 |         Self: LoadQuery<Conn, U>,
     |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `load`
     = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Queryable` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

when I remove the pagination lines in the unit test code, it works fine. Could query data from database successfully. So I think something is going wrong with my pagination code. I read the code but could not figure out where is going wrong, what should I do to fix this problem? This is my `Favorites` define:

```
#[derive( Serialize, Queryable, Deserialize,Default)]
// #[table_name = "favorites"]
pub struct Favorites {
    pub id: i64,
    pub song_id: Option<i64>,
    pub created_time: i64,
    pub updated_time: i64,
    pub user_id: i64,
    pub source_id: String,
    pub like_status: i32,
    pub source: i32,
    pub playlist_id: i64,
    pub play_count: i32,
    pub fetched_download_url: Option<i32>,
    pub downloaded: Option<i32>
}
```

and this is the table DDL in the PostgreSQL 13:

```
-- Drop table

-- DROP TABLE public.favorites;

CREATE TABLE public.favorites (
    id int8 NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    song_id int8 NULL,
    created_time int8 NOT NULL,
    updated_time int8 NOT NULL,
    user_id int8 NOT NULL,
    source_id varchar NOT NULL,
    like_status int4 NOT NULL,
    "source" int4 NOT NULL,
    playlist_id int8 NOT NULL,
    play_count int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    fetched_download_url int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    downloaded int4 NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT favorites_id_seq_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT unique_idx UNIQUE (source_id, user_id)
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fav_uniq_idx ON public.favorites USING btree (source_id, user_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pagination code transforms your query from one returning `Favorites` to one returning `(Favorites, i64)`. It adds a column via `SELECT *, COUNT(*)` to keep track of total counts.

You should either use the provided `.load_and_count_pages()` instead of `.load()` or you can probably get just the original columns by using a `.select()`. The code could possibly be modified to avoid adding the column if you don't need the counts and only need limit and offset.